# Comparing next element in a list Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to figure out how to make sure that the consecutive values are not the same in a list. Expected output: [1, 2, 3]
**Actual output**: [1, 1, 3, 3]

I also tried using `next()` but that gave me "list object is not an iterator"

What is best practices here and what am I doing wrong?

```
def unique_in_order(iterable):

    return [x for x in iterable if not iterable[x] == iterable[x+1]]

print(unique_in_order([1,1,2,2,3,3]))
```

Comment: `for x in iterable` here `x` is the values in the list not the index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it without list comprehensions. Create a list with the first element and iterate over the following pairs

```
def unique_in_order(iterable):
    lst = [iterable[0]]
    for x in range(len(iterable) - 1):
        if iterable[x] != iterable[x + 1]:
            lst.append(iterable[x + 1])
    return lst
```

you can also use `zip`

```
def unique_in_order(iterable):
    lst = [iterable[0]]
    for x, y in zip(iterable, iterable[1:]):
        if x != y:
            lst.append(y)
    return lst
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do it without a list comprehension, you can get better control flow and solve your problem:

```py
def unique_in_order(iterable):
    list = []

    for index, x in enumerate(iterable):
        if index == len(iterable) -1:
            list.append(x)
        elif iterable[index] != iterable[index+1]:
            list.append(x)

    return list
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it using a generator.  It assumes None is not the first value in the list.

```
def unique(lst):
    prev = None
    for val in lst:
        if val != prev:
            prev = val
            yield val

print(list(unique([1,1,2,2,3,3,1,1])))
```

Comment: You can use `prev = object()` as a sentinel value to make this work for iterables containing lists (assuming that there isn't a weird overriding of `__eq__` somewhere).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension, but make sure to add the last element to the returned list.

```
def unique_in_order(lst):
    return [lst[i] for i in range(len(lst)-1) if lst[i] != lst[i+1]] + [lst[-1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be using [`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby

def unique_in_order(iterable):
    return [i[0] for i in groupby(iterable)]
```

It will work for any iterable, not only lists.